# Error message:'nbsp' not defined (symfony1.4)

Tags: php, google-chrome, radio-button, symfony-1.4

I got a problem:

I use sfWidgetFormChoice to make a radio button, but in google chrome a error message is displayed:
**Entity 'nbsp' not defined**

Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space. That ampersand and semi-colon are probably playing havoc on your code. If you can find it, delete it.

Comment: Don't know anything about this framework and this seems somewhat unlikely...but that error suspiciously acknowledges &nbsp; by name as an entity. If there is XML based parsing going on, you have to have a DTD/Schema that that defines named entities used within the markup (of which nbsp is not one by default). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625602/how-to-display-nbsp-in-xml-output

Comment: Thank you guys, I have already fixed it.  Yes, it is about XML..

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are using `&nbsp;`, including the `&` and the `;` (or else it won't work). You can also use `&emsp;` for tab, just so you know