# List server directory using JavaScript XHR

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest, lighttpd

When I asked the question can `javascript` list files on the server, everyone answered with "`javascript` cannot access server filesystem because it is a `client-side scripting language`". But I thought that answer is only partially true, because browser can list the contents of the server directory if `dirlisting` is enabled. So, I decided to try to parse that output - no need to use `cgi` when you can already see the data you need in `xml` format. So here is what I did:

I am using `lighttpd`, and important entries in `lighttpd.conf` are:

```
dir-listing.activate    = "enable"                 #enables directory listing
dir-listing.auto-layout = "disable"                #simplifies the list style
mimetype.assign         = ( ".xml" => "text/xml" ) #deals with xmls
```

`test.xml` used to test `XHR` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<anchors>
 <a>foo</a>
 <a>bar</a>
</anchors>
```

Directory listing page, created by `lighttpd` `mod_dirlisting.so`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<h2>Index of /directory/</h2>
<div class="list">
<table summary="Directory Listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr><th class="n">Name</th><th class="m">Last Modified</th><th class="s">Size</th><th class="t">Type</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="n"><a href="../">Parent Directory</a>/</td><td class="m">&nbsp;</td><td class="s">- &nbsp;</td><td class="t">Directory</td></tr>
<tr><td class="n"><a href="foo">foo</a></td><td class="m">2015-Jan-03 13:24:12</td><td class="s">39.4K</td><td class="t">application/octet-stream</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

`test.html` page used to create `XHR`:

```
<html><head></head><body><script>

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 else var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
 request.open('post', 'test.xml', true);
 request.send();
 if (request) request.onreadystatechange = function() alert(request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue);

</script></body></html>
```

All of which work fine (you get 'foo' in an alert box), but when I `request.open` directory instead of `xml`, I get nothing, not even in error console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your code. For starters, in your JavaScript you are accessing `request.responseXML` before `request.readyState` is `4`. At this point, that property should not be available, so you should be getting some errors on that. This can be fixed fairly easily.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
else var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

request.open('post', 'dir/', true);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
        alert(request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

However, you have another issue. You are trying to parse your output as XML, but it is not a valid XML document, or a valid HTML document for that matter. You would need to have another element wrapping the output for it to be a valid XML document, as there can only be one root node. Additionally, `&nbsp;` is not supported in XML, so that would also need to be removed [or replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625602/how-to-display-nbsp-in-xml-output). Something like the following would work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xml>
<h2>Index of /directory/</h2>
<div class="list">
<table summary="Directory Listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr><th class="n">Name</th><th class="m">Last Modified</th><th class="s">Size</th><th class="t">Type</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="n"><a href="../">Parent Directory</a>/</td><td class="m"></td><td class="s">- </td><td class="t">Directory</td></tr>
<tr><td class="n"><a href="foo">foo</a></td><td class="m">2015-Jan-03 13:24:12</td><td class="s">39.4K</td><td class="t">application/octet-stream</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</xml>
```

You might also be interested in using the `responseType` property of the `XMLHttpRequest`. If you set this property to `'document'`, you can parse HTML response, rather than XML response.

```
request.open('post', 'dir/', true);
request.responseType = 'document';
request.send();
```

Comment: `request.readyState` was omitted for brevity of example code, and `xml` file has been generated by `mod_dirlisting.so` server module, so I cannot manipulate its semi-incorrect output (`&nbsp` etc) in any way, but I can choose to bypass it by parsing the output using `request.responseType = 'document'`, which was actually the direct answer to my problem. Thank you.